# Form Validations goes fire again after calling ng-submit method

Tags: angularjs, forms

I am working in rails + angular application where I have a post index page along with post create form on the same page.

I have a form to create post with Title and content field, I added validation on both field which goes fire on form submit and field blur event.

```
<div class="container-right">
  <form ng-submit=" post_form.$valid && addPost()" style="margin-top:30px;" name="post_form" novalidate>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>New Post</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Post Title" ng-model="post.title" ng-model-options= "{ updateOn : 'default blur'}"name="title" ng-minlength="4" required></input>

        <span ng-show="post_form.$submitted || post_form.title.$touched && post_form.title.$invalid ">
          <div ng-messages="post_form.title.$error">
            <span class="error" ng-message="required">Title is Required</span>
            <span class="error" ng-message="minlength">Use Atleast 4 charater long Title</span>
          </div>
        </span>

      </div>

      <div class="form-group big_input_box">
        <textarea rows="2"  class="form-control" placeholder="Description Of Your Title..." ng-model="post.content" name="content" ng-minlength="10" required></textarea>

        <span ng-show="post_form.$submitted || post_form.content.$touched && post_form.content.$invalid">
          <div ng-messages="post_form.content.$error">
            <span class="error" ng-message="required">We need Your Post description</span>
            <span class="error" ng-message="minlength">Please keep your description atleast 10 charater Long.</span>
          </div>
        </span>

      </div>

      <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
      </div>
    </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

After success validation or in ng-submit method

- I added That post data in my posts table.
- Clear the post form fields
- And add newly added post in post_list array.

the method which called on ng-submit

```
  //  Add a new Post
  $scope.addPost = function() {
    if($scope.post.title) {
      $http.post("/posts.json", {post: $scope.post}).success(function(data){

        // Add newly added post in post list
        $scope.posts_list.push(data);

        Flash.create("success", "Post Successfully Created")

        //clear out the form field
        $scope.post.title = ''
        $scope.post.content = ''
      })
    }
  }
```

After that action the validations of both fields goes fire again.

I tried some solutions like clear out the $scope.post, stop default propagation but did not got solution.

Thanks in advance.

You can check the attached image -    https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QLi8.jpg

Answer (score 0):

`Angular` remembers state of your form after you submitted it.
After success submit your form you would need to reset state of this form.
So after you cleared your models - you need to reset state of your `post_form` by using functions `$setPristine()` and `$setUntouched()`

```
  $scope.addPost = function() {
    if($scope.post.title) {
      $http.post("/posts.json", {post: $scope.post}).success(function(data){

        // Add newly added post in post list
        $scope.posts_list.push(data);

        Flash.create("success", "Post Successfully Created")

        //clear out the form field
        $scope.post.title = ''
        $scope.post.content = ''

    // Here is what you need to do:
        $scope.post_form.$setPristine();
        $scope.post_form.$setUntouched();
      })
    }
  }
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/fVMRkcgB30n5VJcANdFe?p=preview

Comment: Done .....  Great Work Thanks  actually I used that function on my post model instead of form   Thanks......